# Convert connected components to adjacency matrix

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, networkx, graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

l have an adjacency matrix of  16 by 16.

```
 Adjacency=[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

From this adjacency matrix l applied scipy algorithm to determine the connected components as follow :

```
from scipy.sparse.csgraph import connected_components 
supernodes=connected_components(Adjacency)
```

which returns 4 components :

```
 (4, array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 0], dtype=int32))
```

Now the algorithm returns 4 components (4 new nodes or 4 supernodes 0,1,2,3) and its associated adjacency matrix is of dim=(4,4)

My question is as follow :

Given the intial adjacency matrix of 16 by 16 and the connected components, how can l compute efficiently the new adjacency matrix ?

In other way, we need to merge all the nodes that are affected to the same connected component.

**EDIT 1 :**
Here  a concrete example. Given the following adjacency matrix of 6 nodes, dim=-6,6) :

```
Adjacency_matrix=[[0,1,1,0,0,1],
[1,0,0,1,0,0],
[1,0,0,0,1,1],
[0,1,0,0,1,0],
[0,0,1,1,0,0],
[1,0,1,0,0,0]]
```

Given three supernodes as follow :

```
supernodes[0]=[0,2]# supernode 0 merges node 0 and 2
supernodes[1]=[1,4]#supernode 1 merges node 1 and 4
supernodes[2]=[3,5]#supernode 2 merges node 3 and 5
```

**The supposed output :**
Adjacency matrix of 3 supernodes dim=(3,3)

```
reduced_adjacency_matrix=[[0,1,1],
[1,0,1],
[1,1,0]]
```

What does it mean ?

For instance, consider the first supernodes[0]=[0,2]. The idea is as follow :

A) if i and j are in the same supernode then adjacency[i,j]=0

B)if i and j are in the same supernode and i or j has connection with other nodes other than i and j set 1

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Once you shrink each connected component down to a single node, there will be no edges between the remaining components.  So won't the new adjacency matrix be all zeros?  Is there something I'm missing from your question?

Comment: @Joel. Le me explain it in another way. Given an adjacency matrix (10,10) l want to create a new adjacency matrix (5,5) given the new nodes, l want to reduce the number of nodes from 10 to 5 by building 5 super nodes. for instance Supernodes[0]=[1,3] (supernodes[0] contains node 1 and 3)
Supernodes[1]=[6,7]
Supernodes[2]=[5,8]
Supernodes[3]=[4,9]
Supernodes[4]=[0,2] . The new adjacency matrix is composed of supernodes , so how can fill new_adjacency_matrix=np.zeros(shape=(5,5)) . Hope it's clear

Comment: @ericlardon Please edit the question with this description.  It would also be very helpful if you created a small, concrete example that shows the input and the desired output.  Currently the question is confusing, because you have code that shows `supernodes` being the connected components, and as Joel points out, in that case there will not be any edges between your supernodes.

Comment: Is this the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49479401/how-to-merge-nodes-given-an-adjacecny-matrix-and-the-new-list-of-nodes-super-no?  If so, delete one of them, and edit the other as needed.  You don't need to ask the same question twice.

Comment: are you using networkx?

Comment: @Joel, yes l used networkX to generate a random graph and its associated adjacency matrix

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser, please look at my edit 1 where l gave a concrete example

Comment: Consider using `nx.contracted_nodes`: https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.minors.contracted_nodes.html.  Networkx also has commands to find connected components.

Comment: @Joel, What if l have just my adjacency matrix and the list of supernodes, how can l build the contracted the adjacency matrix ? because l use Networkx just for random graph but for real graph l have adjacency matrices and supernodes list. In this case l can't use contracted nodes of networkX. Hope it is clear